# Change call popup to message popup swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have this code:

```
// Get phone number and make a call on tap
if heyObj[HEYS_PHONE] != nil {
    if "\(heyObj[HEYS_PHONE])" != "" {
        let aURL = URL(string: "telprompt://\(heyObj[HEYS_PHONE]!)")!
        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(aURL as URL) {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(aURL)
        } else { simpleAlert(mess: "Sorry, Your device cannot make phone calls!") }

    } else { simpleAlert(mess: "This user has not provided a phone number") }

} else { simpleAlert(mess: "This user has not provided a phone number") }

}
```

What this does:

It gets the phone number from a user and make a call on tap.

The popup looks like this:
[image]

Is it possible to change this from calling to sending a message?

Is there any function available which can do this?

Comment: set open URL as  "sms: #MobileNumber#"

Comment: Where do exactly are you referring to change this?

Comment: let aURL = URL(string: "sms://\(heyObj[HEYS_PHONE]!)")!

Comment: @DarshitShah It's working but now I do not see any popup, it goes straight to the messages.

Comment: in SMS there is no confirmation popup as it will launch the app and allow the user to send if user wish....in calling the number ...asking for confirmation else it will call directly which is wrong as per user experience as its possible that user may tap by mistake

Comment: @DarshitShah Got it. Is it possible to display a popup and ask the user with which app they want to send the message? This might be useful if they have WhatsApp, Viber and so on...

Comment: This will only navigate user to message application not navigate to any other app like whatsapp or else